# Android native SIP recommendation libraries

Tags: android, mobile, sip, voip

I was looking into Android SIP stack, but I don't see funcionabilities that I need such as mute, hold and transfer a call.

Which library do you recommend to implement these funcionabilities?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend

1. [Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/) ([sample app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.linphone))
2. [Csipsimple](https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) ([sample app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csipsimple&hl=en))

Both of them is easy to implement (Linphone is easier in my opinion) and if you need more feature you can add it by yourself in Csipsimple because it's an open source project.